# How to validate the Reactive formControl/formArray on submit

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I have a **Parent** formGroup with a formArray as control. This formArray contains an **Child** formGroup.

### Purpose

The purpose is to validate all controls of a **specific** field in the formGroup inside the formArray **onSubmit**.

**The form is a reactiveForm**

---

**Eg**: **Parent formGroup**

```
 parentForm = this.fb.group({
    formArray: this.fb.array([]),
  });
```

Child formGroup

```
childForm = this.fb.group({
   //field which need to be validated onSubmit manually
   field1: this.fb.control('',{
   validators: myCustomValidator
   }),
   //this field doesn't need to be validate on submit
   field2: this.fb.control('')
}
```

```
 let formArray = this.parentForm.get('formArray') as formArray //Get it as formArray
    formArray.push(this.childForm(data)) //Push the data into the childForm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to get the control of the specific field in the **child** formGroup.
We iterate the formArray and get the individual control of the formGroup's

For manually **validate** and update the changed value, we can use [updateValueAndValidity](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity)

```
submitForm() :void
{
 for(const childGroup of this.formArray().controls)
{
childGroup.get('field1')?.updateValueAndValidity(); //Validate and Update the control manually
}
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use **updateOn** property and set it to submit, but it may not work as intended sometimes

```
childForm = this.fb.group({
   //field which need to be validated onSubmit manually
   field1: this.fb.control('',{
   updateOn: 'submit'
   validators: myCustomValidator
   }),
   //this field doesn't need to be validate on submit
   field2: this.fb.control('')
}
```